# Passive vs. active investing past performance comparison/data?

Tags: investing, index-fund, historical-data, investment-strategies

I am looking for past statistical data how on average active investment (managed by fund manager) compares to passive investment (index) in 10 or 20 past years.

I intend to compare the average gains in having active investment and subtract fees (appr 1.5% vs 0.25%) to make it easier to decide which way is more efficient to invest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Telegraph had an interesting article recently going back 30 years for Mutual's in the UK that had beaten the market and trackers for both IT and UT

http://www.telegraph.co.uk/finance/personalfinance/investing/11489789/The-funds-that-have-returned-more-than-12pc-per-year-for-THIRTY-years.html